# error encountered while creating a virtual environment in Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

The following error occurred while creating a virtual environment (I'm using Ubuntu in VM virtual box on a windows computer):

[image]

How should I fix this issue?

Comment: The error is in reasonably plain language: Package not found. Since the package IS at http://packages.ubuntu.com, check your package name for typos. Then check that the proper source for the package is enabled. Then remember to run `sudo apt update`. Then try the install again.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code